# How to build Tauri app with open JS code?

Tags: javascript, tauri

Is it possible to build a tauri project in such a way that the javascript code remains open and editable so that I don't have to recompile the whole project?

I searched for a similar question on the Internet and did not find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's `tauri dev`'s default behavior

However javascript doesn't have `HMR` you can use `vite` instead: https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/setup/vite